# Are there any good tricks to help remember RegEx?

Tags: regex

I don't always write Regular Expressions, but when I do, I feel like I'm learning it all over again. I'm looking for methods to retain the important parts, and put some method to the madness.

Comment: Not being a specific programming problem, this strikes me as off-topic. It _might_ be more appropriate for [programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) for its focus on learning/concepts.

Comment: Set up a wiki and put them there.

Comment: Actually, I'm aware this kind of question doesn't fit the paradigm of SO, so I welcome a move to wiki, just didn't know how to go about it initially.

Comment: The only important syntax parts are classes and quantifiers. The rest will take a few years, because after syntax comes a lot of thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the exact same trick that's used for remembering any API: use an accurate reference.

For example, when I need to work with Regular Expressions in JavaScript, I use [the reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). If I need regex in PHP, I'll use [the php.net reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). If I need regex in .NET, I'll use [the MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc).

It's better to not remember and look it up each time than it is to remember incorrectly and write it wrong.

Comment: +1 on look up in manual when you don't grasp it to the good confidence  level

Answer (score 2):

Let's rephrase this:

#### I don't always write `German Language`, but when I do, I feel like I'm learning it all over again. I'm looking for methods to retain the important `words` ...

**Regular expressions** is just an extreme compact and concise **language** for communication with a problem solver (it's engine). When learning a language, you normally repeat **IDIOMS** of this language many many times until your brain decides they have some importance and will keep the idioms and their context available.

A tool per se will, imho, not help at all in the long term. Don't tease yourself. Only repetition and practice will. The best thing for many people is a **systematic study** of the topic, starting from the simplest idioms. A good book will help a lot if you can follow through the rising levels of complexity.

**[Here is a book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do)** which I consider excellent for this purpose.

Javascript and PHP are languages that support their regex flavors and allow practicing regular expressions. For javascript, you'll only need an editor and a browser. For PHP, an good IDE w/syntax checking would be advantageous for the start.

Comment: For JS you really only need a browser (F12).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe RegexBuddy could help you? It has many capabilities helping to analyse regexes.

Answer (score 0):

I always jump back to http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex.  It's a real-time editor with a quick-reference on the side.

Answer (score 0):

> Practice makes perfect.
>   James Bond I guess

Consider this.
1. Hack into and try to construct by yourself tricky regexps
2. Help people here on stackoverflow to make regexps ))
3. Concentrate, say play with regexps one hour every day during a week and give
it more hours if you enjoys this
4. Take your time and enjoy the process

Comment: most of time I just used `man grep`, there is a good section, GRE and BRE

Answer (score 0):

I can't count how many times I've visited http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html for a quick reference. In fact I believe that's where I learned regexes in the first place. It features a short, no-nonsense description of all the common regex features, with plenty of examples and links in each section to more info.

(no affiliation)